# Delete rows that do not contain specific text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tabular file that looks like this:

```
query_name      KEGG_KOs
PROKKA_00013    NaN
PROKKA_00015    bactNOG[38]
PROKKA_00017    NA|NA|NA
PROKKA_00019    K00240
PROKKA_00020    K00246
PROKKA_00022    K02887
```

I'm trying to create a script to go through and delete the entire row if column 2 ('KEGG_KOs') does not begin with 'K0'. I'm trying to create an output of:

```
query_name     KEGG_KOs
PROKKA_00019    K00240
PROKKA_00020    K00246
PROKKA_00022    K02887
```

Previous responses have referred people to pandas DataFrame but I've had no luck using those responses to help. Any would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

I had tried (but this only isolates a specific K0 line.

```
df = pd.read_csv("eggnog.txt", delimiter="\t", names=["#query_name", "KEGG_KOs"])
print(df.loc[df['KEGG_KOs'] == 'K00240'])
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far and what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) or [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `regex` for start of string `^` and parameter `na=False`, because missing values:

```
df1 = df[df['KEGG_KOs'].str.startswith('K0', na=False)]
print (df1)
     query_name KEGG_KOs
3  PROKKA_00019   K00240
4  PROKKA_00020   K00246
5  PROKKA_00022   K02887
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['KEGG_KOs'].str.contains('^K0', na=False)]
```

Comment: Is this possible to do with many strings?  Something like `df1 = df[df['KEGG_KOs'].str.contains('^K0', '^K1', na=False)]`

Comment: @Aragol - Try `df1 = df[df['KEGG_KOs'].str.contains('^K0|^K1', na=False)]`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with two columns as well? I tried `df1 = df[df['KEGG_KOs', 'KEGG_K1s' ].str.contains('^K0|^K1', na=False)]` but it didn't work @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

you can use open as read and then write. assume the original file saved as old.txt and the updated one will be saved as new.txt

```
text = ''
with open("old.txt", 'r') as org:
    next(org)
    for line in org:
        data = line.strip().split()
        if data[1].startswith("K0"):
            text = text + data[0] + " "+ data[1] + '\n'

w = open('new.txt', 'w')
w.write("query_name"+" "+ "KEGG_KOs\n")
w.write(text)
w.close()
```